# How to start / stop proftpd

Tags: ftp, rhel5, proftpd

I can't seem to find a way to stop / re-start proftpd. My server IP address is xx.yy.zz.ww and connecting from external devices via FTP gives me the prompt:

```
Connected to xx.yy.zz.ww
220 ProFTPD 1.3.1 Server (ProFTPD)
```

It then asks me for username.

Same thing happens when I try to connect from the same server (ftp localhost). Thus, I have established that proftp is running on my server .

Also, on my server (xx.yy.zz.ww) . I am tailing `/var/log/messages` and it shows me FTP session opened and closed.

I can't find how is the proftpd is working. 
/etc/init.d/  doesn't have proftpd ; /etc/xinetd.d/ doesn't have proftpd.

I looked at: `/etc/proftpd.conf` and it shows me `ServerType  inetd`

also, when I run: `ps -auxfww` | grep proftp I don't get anything (except my current command)

How can I find out that proftp is running and how do I kill it / restart it ?

Comment: Have you checked /etc/xinetd.conf, it is possible to put the configuration there as opposed to /etc/xinetd.d/*

Comment: I checked it. There is nothing in the xinetd.conf except for the default template  defaults{}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use netstat to see what process is holding port 21:

```
# netstat -tnlp
```

And from there you can use RPM to see what package owns the file to stop it and remove it from `init.d`.

Comment: sorry, linux noob here.. bear with me. This is what I get `cp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      26848/xinetd`  How do I proceed further

Comment: Well then it's `xinetd` that is serving it. You can stop/restart it by xinetd's script. Do a `grep ftp` on `xinetd.d` and xinetd.conf and see if there's any reference to it.

Comment: this is what I get [root@s87998 xinetd.d]# cat /etc/xinetd.d/ftp_psa service ftp { disable = no socket_type = stream protocol = tcp wait = no user = root instances = UNLIMITED server = /usr/sbin/in.proftpd server_args = -c /etc/proftpd.conf }

Comment: Thanks, finally this worked: chkconfig ftp_psa on/off ..

Answer (score 4):

If your server has Plesk ProFTPD daemon is `xinetd`. Use

> /etc/init.d/xinetd restart

Answer (score 1):

To stop proftpd

```
/sbin/service proftpd stop
```

to stop it from starting with the system

```
/sbin/chkconfig proftpd off
```

to start proftpd with the system

```
/sbin/chkconfig proftpd on
```

to manually start proftpd

```
/sbin/service proftpd start
```

and to restart it

```
/sbin/service proftpd restart
```

Comment: proftpd: unrecognized service

Comment: nice service proftpd restart worked for me =)

Answer (score 1):

`cp 0 0 0.0.0.0:21 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 26848/xinetd` means that your proftpd is controlled by xinetd. xinetd provides the ability to start a deamon only when someone calls a specific port. Please check /etc/xinetd.d/ for files which point to an ftp-server (for example "service ftp" in headline.

Comment: cool.. this is what I get [root@s87998 xinetd.d]# cat /etc/xinetd.d/ftp_psa

service ftp
{
       disable         = no
       socket_type     = stream
       protocol        = tcp
       wait            = no
       user            = root
       instances       = UNLIMITED
       server          = /usr/sbin/in.proftpd
       server_args     = -c /etc/proftpd.conf
}

Comment: But, when I try to do this: [root@s87998 xinetd.d]# /etc/xinetd.d/ftp_psa status
-bash: /etc/xinetd.d/ftp_psa: Permission denied

Comment: Hey,  this worked: chkconfig ftp_psa on/off ! Thanks for helping me find out the service name ..

Answer (score 0):

You can generally find out the status of a service like this:

```
service proftpd status
```

And you can likewise restart (or similarly start and stop) like this:

```
service proftpd restart
```

Comment: Already did that earlier, `[root@s87998 /]# service proftpd status
proftpd: unrecognized service`

Comment: It might be called just `ftpd` on your system. You might be able to browse for the service name by scanning the init.d files: `ls /etc/rc.d/init.d/` or wherever your system has those.